# Perform includes on key object, using LINQ, in a GroupBy situation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a relatively simple, yet somehow weirdly complicated case whereby I need to perform includes on a lengthy object graph, when I'm doing a group-by.

Here is roughly what my LINQ looks like:

```
var result = DbContext.ParentTable
    .Where(p => [...some criteria...])
    .GroupBy(p => p.Child)
    .Select(p => new 
    {
        ChildObject = p.Key,
        AllTheThings = p.Sum(p => p.SomeNumericColumn),
        LatestAndGreatest = p.Max(p => p.SomeDateColumn)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.SomeTotal)
    .Take(100)
    .ToHashSet();
```

That gives me a listing of anonymous objects, just the way I want it, with child objects neatly associated with some aggregate stats about said object. Fine. But I also need a fair share of the object graph associated with child object.

This ask gets even a bit messier than it might otherwise be, when I want to use existing code, I already have to perform the includes. I.e., I have a static method which will take an IQueryable of my child object and, based upon parameters, give me back another IQueryable, with all the proper includes that I need (there are rather a lot of them).

I can't seem to figure the correct way to take my child object as a queryable, and give that to my include method, such that I get it back, for expansion at the point I want to express it to the new anonymous object (where I'm saying ChildObject = n.Key).

Sorry if this is something of a duplicate -- I did search around and found solutions that were close to what I'm wanting, here but not quite.

Comment: "*I can't seem to figure the correct way to take my child object as a queryable, and give that to my include method,*" can you expand on this point maybe another way, im not sure i quite understand what you mean

Comment: @TheGeneral: Agreed, not well-worded, sorry about that. What I want is for the child object to have all its includes, simple as that. One solution would be to obtain those using a .Include between the .GroupBy and .Select (I assume). But there are a LOT of includes I need and I've already written a method to get those -- I'd like to use that. I was trying to say that I have to give my include method an IQueryable<ChildObject> but don't know how to do that from within the Linq query.

Comment: Does including the child dependencies after `DbContext.ParentTable` not work ? e.g `DbContext.ParentTable.Includ(x => x.Child.<stuff>)`

Comment: I can say DbContext.ParentTable...GroupBy(p => p.Child).Include(p => p.Key.ChildProperty).ThenInclude(c => c.SomethingElse) etc... but those includes don't become part of the .Select, which happens next. I.e., the p.Key which ends-up in the .Select doesn't have the includes, since p.Key is from the .GroupBy, not the original IQueryable (I think). So it does not work that way. Also, I don't want to have to put the .Include inline with the Linq syntax -- I want to have my custom include method do that.